# Mapping custom geom_point on sf object

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I try to map a geom_point with "custom" coordinates on a sf-object. At first, I receive an error message (I assume because the coordinates are not in the same format). After fixing this issue in the way the error message suggests, however, the point does not appear on the output map (while the map itself is produced). If this is still because of a format-difference between my coordinates, how do I make sure that both point and sf share the same format, ie how can I retrieve the coordinate-format of my sf and use it for my customized geom_points?

```
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

city <- data.frame(name = "raleigh", lat = 45.48067, lng = -122.76204)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = city, aes(x = lng, y = lat), color = 'red')

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc) 

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = city, aes(x = lng, y = lat), color = 'red') +
  geom_sf(data = nc) 

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = nc) + 
  coord_sf(lims_method = "geometry_bbox") +
  geom_point(data = city, aes(x = lng, y = lat), color = 'red')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm.. The point appears on your map.

```r
library(ggplot2)
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

city <- data.frame(name = "raleigh", lat = 45.48067, lng = -122.76204)

ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = city, aes(x = lng, y = lat), color = 'red') +
  geom_sf(data = nc)
```

[image]

However, as the coordinates are far, far west from `nc`, it doesn't "match" with `nc` object.

<sup>Created on 2022-10-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: There were two errors in my code: First, I selected the wrong city. However, even with the correct coordinates, it did not show up. Then I saw that I was loading a ggplot-style in my packages and when I removed it, the dot showed up! Thank you for pointing out the error that one could spot in my code